# How to access xsd file from a http wsdl url?

Tags: xsd, wsdl, soapui, filenotfoundexception

I have wsdl URL. But testing it by code is a big ask. So found SoapUI and thought it could mock up data for calling it easily and find the right set of parameters. I saved the wsdl url output from browser to a file.wsdl and loaded into SoapUI, but getting an error that xsd file is missing. But how to find out the xsd files ? Is there a way to extract xsd files from http url and place it in same folder as the wsdl. ?

I have not worked with web services before and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To strictly deal with your ask which is to capture XSD content in the same folder...

In theory, the ask involves two major steps:

- Files download by recursively following all external references (wsdl:import and/or xsd:include/xsd:import statements).
- Fix all references between files, IF the original files were not all in the same folder.

If you have the .NET platform, you could use [disco.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy2a3ybs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It automates the download but it doesn't fix the references between XSD files.

When I have to do it, I use [QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com) (I am associated with it). There's a utility in the Tools tab, under the WSDL group.

[image]

Fill in the prompt as needed, then press **Load**. Whatever files are found, will be listed in the **External**... list.

[image]

When files and paths match whatever expectations you may have, press OK and you're done.

Comment: disco.exe Worked !
Are there any good sources in understanding all these soap,xsd, wsdl process from a practical viewpoint and in-depth explanations? Have read in many websites, but they are not very deep. Thought asking someone who work on it can provide better sources. Thanks!